# React, Graphql fetching a list

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Can you please check what I'm doing wrong here?

In my schema I have a type named `HoteDetailsType` and a field inside `addOns` in reference of another type `HotelAddOnsType`

```
 type HotelAddOnsType = {
  name: string
  description: string
  price: number
}
```

```
type HotelDetailsType = {
  addOns: HotelAddOnsType[]
  guestName: string
  numberOfRooms: number
  totalPrice: number
}
```

When I try to display the data, all field is displaying properly except `addOns`

`const hotelDetails: HotelDetailsType = data.getHotelDetailsByIds.items[0]`

This is how I call it,
 `<Text>{hotelDetails.addOns.name}</Text>`
`<Text>{hotelDetails.addOns.description}</Text>`

and receiving this error
`Property 'name' does not exist on type 'HotelAddOnsType[]'.`

Any workaround on this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hotelDetails.addOns is an array of objects..

So you have access through index or map through the values to get the data..

eg:

```
 hotelDetails.addOns[0].name
```

or

```
{hotelDetails.addOns.map((data) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p>{data.name}</p>
            <p>{data.description}</p>
            {data.price}
          </>
        );
      })}
```